# Open file location from hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to when I click the hyperlink in Excel file location opening and file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub OpenFileInLocation()

Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String

FPath = "C:\EPDM\EPDM LIBRARY\TEST"
FName = "test.txt"
Shell "explorer.exe /select," & FPath & "\" & FName, vbMaximizedFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: You can also use the `FollowHyperlink` method for this.

Comment: Can ı do it without macro? I dont wanto use makro